# How to use comma and dot as delimiter in addition with Java default delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file which contains lot of permutations and combinations of special characters, white space and data.
I am storing the content of this file into an array list, and if i am not using `useDelimiter()` function, Java is reading my text perfectly.

The only issue is that its not accepting *comma* (`,`) and *dot* (`.`) as delimiter.

I know I can use `input.useDelimiter(",|.| |\n")` to use *comma* , *dot*, *space* as delimiter and others options as well, but then the results I get are not correct as java gives me now.

Is there a way to instruct java to use *comma* and *dot* as delimiters along with whatever default delimiter it uses?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: If you have numbers with commas and/or dots it might be best to just use a BufferedReader and `split("[\\.,\\s]")`. Or immediately some third party CSVReader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default delimiter for Scanner is defined as the pattern `\p{javaWhitespace}+`, so if you want to also treat comma and dot as a delimiter, try

`input.useDelimiter("(\\p{javaWhitespace}|\\.|,)+");`

Note you need to escape dot, as that is a special character in regular expressions.

Comment: Man !! I was trying to implement this from around 2 days....Couldn't get better result than this. Perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Its giving me results exactly how I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Use escaped character like this:

```
input.useDelimiter("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
String str = "...";
List<String> List = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
```

Basically the .split() method will split the string according to (in this case) delimiter you are passing and will return an array of strings.

However, you seem to be after a List of Strings rather than an array, so the array must be turned into a list by using the Arrays.asList() utility. Just as an FYI you could also do something like so:

```
String str = "...";
ArrayList<String> List = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
```